# How to use Ruby on Rails with Sublime Text (Gems)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, sublimetext

I know how to create new projects with ruby, and I've seen videos of people using it, but then I see them open a text editor with the name of their project (the one that they created with rails) and the Gems. Can someone help me understand this and how to use it? I am trying to create a simple login/logout/ and register page

Comment: Check out http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/06/21/sublime-text-2-for-ruby/

Answer (score 2):

Here the best link you could ever have [here](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/06/21/sublime-text-2-for-ruby/)

1.Install the subl command line tool

2.Install Package Control. Package Control makes it easy to install/remove/upgrade packages `Preference->packagecontrol`

3.Once you find the package control you can install as many packages as you want **including Theme, a XDEBUG , RUBY related stuff by searching.**

ENjoy!

Comment: Link-only answers are [heavily discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259), as if the link changes or disappears, the answer is worthless. Instead, provide an actual answer in your post, leaving the link for reference.